# Relevance of z-score in the age of computers

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, education, central-limit-theorem

In this the modern age of computers, standard normal probabilities don't need to be looked up in a table. What is more, any normal probability can be easily calculated by a computer. So are normal probability tables still relevant? If not, are z-scores still relevant? To what extent?

Comment: You seem to have two mixed questions here.  One is whether z-scores are relevant. 
 They are useful for certain questions.  One is about whether z-score tables are useful.  I find it faster to look up the Wikipedia table than to start up some software like a spreadsheet or Python to compute z-scores and probabilities.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you. I meant it as a multi-level question. First "are tables relevant?" Then "if they're not, are z-scores still relevant?" I will edit accordingly. Can you tell me or direct me to the kinds of questions you have in mind that they're useful for? And regarding software or a spreadsheet, what about just using Wolfram Alpha? I can input an integral there very fast and I suppose all my students can too.

Comment: Alpha is fine, too.  I find the tables faster to use so I haven't learned the syntax for the other options.  The sort of question they are useful for is when you have a normally distributed random variable and want to know the chance a sample will be greater than some value, or the average of some samples will be greater than some number, or others.  They come up here regularly.

Comment: My feeling, @RossMillikan, is that even for questions of that sort, using a computer 
to do the integration numerically is faster, simpler, and more reliable.

Comment: $z$-scores and the standard normal functions $\Phi(x), \phi(x), \Phi^{-1}(p)$ are all useful, since the location and scale adjustments for a normal distribution are so simple.  I rarely use tables any more but I often standardise, partly because I remember $1.96$ (or a simplification $2$) standard deviations are useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insightful question: As one can see by the comments, this is a matter of opinion. As a textbook author in
'this modern age', I have given this issue some thought. So here is my opinion.

It is true that many routine problems involving normal distributions are easily solved using software. To an extent that statistics and probability texts of the future will start to have different kinds of drill problems.

With access to suitable software, printed normal tables
would no longer be needed. But some problems may be
easier to solve using standard scores--as in (4) below.

Also, some non-computational conceptual discussions will
essentially use standard scores:  "In a normal distribution about 68% of the probbility lies within one standard deviation of the mean.

Four problems using normal distributions:

(1) If scores on a national test are normally distributed with mean 200 and standard deviation 30, what fraction of those taking the test will score below 173? In R, where `pnorm` is a normal CDF:

```
pnorm(173, 200, 30)
[1] 0.1840601
```

(2) If State U undertakes to admit applicants scoring in the top 15% on this exam, what score should be published in the Catalog as the minimal acceptable score? In R, where `qnorm` is an inverse CDF or quantile function:

```
ceiling(qnorm(.85, 200, 30))
[1] 232                      # Publish 232
1 - pnorm(231.5, 200, 30)
[1] 0.1468591                # Check: < 15%
```

(3) Boxes of breakfast cereal are filled automatically by machine, with an average of 15.1 oz and a standard deviation of 0.2 oz.
What percentage of the boxes will contain less than 15 oz.? From R, we get $0.3085,$ almost 31%.

```
pnorm(15, 15.1, .2)
[1] 0.3085375
```

(4) Suppose government regulations require no more than 15% of boxes to contain less than the "15. oz." printed on the box. To what average number $\mu$ of ounces should the filling machine be set? Round up to the nearest 0.01 of an ounce.

This question
may be most easily solved using standard scores:

$$ 0.15 = P(X \le 15)
= P\left(Z =\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{15 - \mu}{.2}\right).$$

We still don't need printed normal tables. In R:

```
qnorm(.15, 0, 1)
[1] -1.036433
```

Then set $(15-\mu)/.2 = -1.036433$ to get $\mu = 15.21.$
And use R to check:

```
pnorm(15, 15.21, .2)
[1] 0.1468591
```

Using R directly would require a 'grid search' using vectors in R. (Either that or tedious trial and error.)

```
mu = seq(15, 17, by = .01) # guessing 17 is too high
pr = pnorm(15, mu, .2)
min(mu[pr <= .15])
[1] 15.21
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I'm a little confused by "pnorm is a binomial CDF". Did you mean "normal CDF"?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this error. Fixed now.

Comment: Notice that your (4) can be easily answered in, say, Desmos by just having a slider for the variable $\mu$ and adjusting it: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wzuhcvrlur. No need to convert to standard normal.

Comment: @QuinnCulver: Interesting. Guess moving the slider is a manual grid search.